# Why bootstrap accordion not working with react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-accordion

```js
import cx from 'classnames';

import Styles from './experience.module.css';

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>


const Experience = () => {
    return (
        <div className={cx('container-fluid g-0', Styles.MainAbout)}>
            <h3 className={cx('col ', Styles.MainTop)}>
                02. My Timeline -------------------
            </h3>
            <div className={cx('col', Styles.Tabs)}>
                <div className="accordion" id="accordionExample">
                    <div className="accordion-item">
                        <h2 className="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
                            <button className="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                Accordion Item #1
                            </button>
                        </h2>
                        <div id="collapseOne" className="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                            <div className="accordion-body">
                                <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="accordion-item">
                        <h2 className="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
                            <button className="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                Accordion Item #2
                            </button>
                        </h2>
                        <div id="collapseTwo" className="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                            <div className="accordion-body">
                                <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="accordion-item">
                        <h2 className="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
                            <button className="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                                Accordion Item #3
                            </button>
                        </h2>
                        <div id="collapseThree" className="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                            <div className="accordion-body">
                                <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </div>

    );

}


export default Experience;
```

[image]

Comment: You probably shouldn't use a "latest" CDN link in your app, as that can lead to unpredictable results when the library is updated. Instead, install the NPM package. Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: What's not working? It's unclear just from your snippet and screen shot what you're referring to the issue is.